# Sublime Text shortcut for stepping into a function

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Eclipse, one can use `ctrl + click` to go directly to a function definition.

For example:

```
f = my_tool.main()
```

If I `ctrl + click` on `main()`, then I will be directed to the code for the main function in the `my_tool` module.

Is there a equivalent functionality in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Daniel's answer is the standard way for a ST user of achieving what you want, you can get a similar feature with the help of [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin. You can highlight a method or class > right click > goto definition. Or you can configure custom keyboard shortcut so that you can highlight and press the defined keyboard combination and you'll be taken to the method definition.

Answer (score 3):

Something somewhat similar is to press `ctrl+p` and type `<filename>@<methodname>`. As usual Sublime uses fuzzy search so you don't have to be very exact when doing this.

Another nifty little trick is to do the same but instead type `<filename>:<linenumber>`, which will take you directly to that line. This is handy when you get exceptions or errors.

Comment: hey thanks.  This is somewhat close, but it still involves manually typing in the name of the class / function.  Is there a way to auto-populate that text input with the function currently selected or based on the cursor position?

Comment: No, I'd say that this is one of the differences between an IDE and an texteditor. You're supposed to be typing not clicking. :P Actually your hands don't have to leave the keyboard in eclipse either, can put the cursor over a method or class and press `F3` to get almost the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to install [CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) for SublimeText.

The default bindings allow you to either place your cursor in the function name and type `ctrl + t, ctrl + t`, or use the mouse binding and do `ctrl + shift + left-click`.  This will take you to the function definition, either in the same file or a different file.  You can then do `ctrl + t, ctrl + b` or `ctrl + shift + right-click` to jump back.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done in Sublime Text. If you hover over an identifier it will now pop up with a menu that can lead to the definition. This is rather slow to wait for the pop-up and you wanted the Ctrl+Click. To get it you need to add a custom mouse binding. How to make one and where to save it can be found in the [Sublime Text Mouse Binding Docs](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/mouse_bindings.html#file-format).

For example on my Linux machine to get to the right directory use `Preferences > Browse Packages...` and find the `User` directory in this folder. In the `User` directory add a `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` file. **Note: The Linux part will be different if you are not on linux. I think the identifiers are `Windows` and `OSX`.**
Within the file you can add this:

```json
[
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "count": 1,
        "modifiers": ["alt"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"additive": true}
    },
    {
        "button": "button1",
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "count": 1,
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```

The first entry is to reassign the previous functionality of creating multiple cursors to Alt+Click. The second assigns goto definition to Ctrl+Click.